# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.notes'

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I try to create a django project. I have some problems with url configurations. The modules that I need, can't be found. Here is my directory's hierarchy:
    .

```
 ├── db.sqlite3
    ├── manage.py
    ├── mysite
    │   ├── asgi.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── settings.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── urls.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── wsgi.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── settings.py
    │   ├── urls.py
    │   └── wsgi.py
    ├── notes
    │   ├── admin.py
    │   ├── apps.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── migrations
    │   │   ├── 0001_initial.py
    │   │   ├── __init__.py
    │   │   └── __pycache__
    │   │       ├── 0001_initial.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── models.py
    │   ├── __pycache__
    │   │   ├── admin.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   ├── models.cpython-37.pyc
    │   │   └── views.cpython-37.pyc
    │   ├── tests.py
    │   └── views.py
    └── static
        └── templates
            ├── __init__.py
            └── note.html
```

I have edited the urls.py file:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from mysite.notes import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.home, name="home")
]
```

When I try to run my server, it says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 332, in execute
    self.check()
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 351, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 73, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 40, in check_url_namespaces_unique
    all_namespaces = _load_all_namespaces(resolver)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 57, in _load_all_namespaces
    url_patterns = getattr(resolver, 'url_patterns', [])
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 536, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 36, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/home/alpaca/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 529, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/mnt/c/Users/cotic/PycharmProjects/final/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    from mysite.notes import views
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mysite.notes
```

Comment: If that's your directory structure then indeed, as it says, there is no such module as `mysite.notes`. `notes` and `mysites` are both packages, not modules, that are siblings of each other.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see there is no module names mysites.notes. I think you were tring to import a file from the notes app. You can import so by using

```
from notes import app #here I am importing apps.py but you can import any file.
```

The reason you are facing this error is that the Django server is run from manage.py file which is outside any folder, hence all paths from mapped from that file.